# Why is the tsconfig path mapping not working?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, path, tsconfig, react-18

I have a problem with the path mapping in my react-18 (ts version 4.6.3) project (created using cra).

I have the following **tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    },
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
     "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

In "**src/context/stores/sort.ts**" I try to import a function from a file in the **utils directory** like so:

```
import { deleteUrlParam } from "utils/url";
```

The file surely exists and vs code is also not complaining about anything.

But when compiling, I get the error "**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils/url'** in..."

I want to know why this happens. Is this a webpack problem? I googled a bunch of examples and they seem to be the exact same as mine.

Comment: could you share all your **tsconfig**

Comment: @monim edited it accordingly

Comment: everythong seems okey ! maybe you have to  close & reopen vscode

Comment: @monim I tried all that stuff. I restarted vscode. I reloaded the window from vscode. I restarted the application. I restarted my pc. Nothing worked.